# javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to locate object to be marshalled in model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jaxb2, oxm

I've looked around bit but can't figure out what am I missing trying to get xml view of result.

Following is the exception I am getting:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to locate object to be marshalled in model: {movies=[com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie@1450f1f, com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie@ac622a, com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie@160c21a, com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie@1677737, com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie@1c3dc66]}
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView.renderMergedOutputModel(MarshallingView.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    ...
    ...
```

Following are the files included in handling the request:

**servlet application context file**

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="movies" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
</bean>
```

**domain object**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    public Movie() {}
    //interesting stuff
}
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MoviesController {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MoviesController.class);

    @Autowired
    private MovieManagementService movieManagementService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findAllMovies(Model model) {
        List<Movie> movies = movieManagementService.getAllMovies();
        model.addAttribute("movies", movies);
        return "movies";
    }   
        //interesting stuff
}
```

Could someone help me out with what I might be missing here?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I am basically trying to see BeanNameViewResolver in action for which I already have BeanNameViewResolver configured in the configuration file as following:

```
<bean id="beanNameViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: You're trying to return xml?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes, am trying to return xml view of the result of the `/movies` request handled by the controller.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes, but I wanted to see `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver` in action.

Comment: Then you would have to have a bean called `movies` in your context. I don't think objects in your model are considered beans.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Sorry should have been more clear with the question for what I was testing, have edited the question. Yes, I already have `movies` declared as a bean in the context.

Comment: Try putting just one `Movie` object instead of the `List`. You might have to make a wrapper object to contain the list and add that wrapper class to your bound classes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: `<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
 <property name="classesToBeBound">
  <bean class="com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie" />
 </property>
</bean>` is giving me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'classesToBeBound[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value`.

Comment: Why'd you change that? Put that back as it was. That property is expecting an array of Class, which you do with the `<list>` tag as you had it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Sorry I misunderstood. Yes, just putting one movie in the Model is working just fine. I think its coming to me now. Seem to have forgotten quite a bit :). Thanks a ton. Will post the answer once it works with the wrapper object. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think JAXB knows how to straight up marshal a standalone `List`. Make a class called `MovieList` and have your list as its property. Then add that class to the `classesToBeBound` and shove it in the model. That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following changes got things working:

**wrapper for Movie class to keep JAXB happy**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="movies")
public class MovieList {

    private List<Movie> movieList;

    public MovieList() {}
    public MovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.movieList = movieList;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="movie")
    public List<Movie> getMovieList() {
        return movieList;
    }
    public void setMovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.movieList = movieList;
    }

}
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String findAllMovies(Model model) throws MovieNotFoundException {
    List<Movie> movieList = movieManagementService.getAllMovies();
    MovieList movies = new MovieList(movieList);
    model.addAttribute("movies", movies);
    return "movies";
}
```

**sevlet application context**

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.Movie</value>
            <value>com.wickedlynotsmart.imdb.model.MovieList</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```